# Что означает точка между 10 и f

Tags: c, структуры

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

union floatint{
    float f;
    int i;
};

void main() {
    union floatint u = {10.f};
    printf("%f\n", u.f);
    printf("%x\n", u.i);
    getch();
}
```

В этом примере пытаются рассмотреть представление числа с плавающей точкой.Непонятно, что делает точка после числа 10 и в целом как инициализируется структура.Еще непонятно , что значит вывести представление числа с плавающей точкой, разве не должен быть выведен знак , целое, мантисса ?

Comment: Число с плавающей точкой означает

Comment: @Duoxx, а разве не без точки пишется ?

Comment: Тут просто нули отброшены по ненадобности (я могу и ошибатся)

Comment: В С: `int main(void)`, а не `void main()`.

Comment: @AnT, а можно  void main(void) ?

Comment: Нет. В стандартном языке `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Синтаксис плавающей константы в С и С++ требует наличия либо десятичной точки, либо экспоненциальной части.

Вариант с десятичной точкой позволяет опускать нулевую целую часть (до точки) или нулевую плавающую часть (после точки). Т.е. константа `10.0` может быть записана как `10.`, а константа `0.5` как `.5`, если вам так больше нравится.

Суффикс `f` придает плавающей константе тип `float` и никак не мешает применению вышеописанного правила. Т.е. можно писать `10.0f`, а можно - `10.f`. Это одно и то же.

Ни С, ни С++ не допускают синтаксис, в котором нет ни десятичной точки, ни экспоненциальной части, а есть только "плавающий" суффикс. То есть наличие `f` в записи `10f` не делает эту запись корректной записью плавающей константы. Можно `10.f`, можно `1e1f`, но не `10f`.

Представленный вами код как раз и выводит представление плавающего числа в виде "знак, экспонента, мантисса" при условии, что размеры типов в вашем `union` совпадают. Просто эти три компоненты выводятся в шестнадцатеричной записи и при выводе не отделены друг от друга. Ну и целый тип в такой роли, разумеется, надо было использовать именно *беззнаковый*, а не совершенно не уместный в этой роли `int`. Уместнее всего было использовать массив из `unsigned char`.

Comment: ,а если бы структура выглядела так : union types
{
  float f;
  unsigned char b[4];
}; и в поле f введено число 10 , то что бы вывелось от такого printf("%f = %x %x %x %x", value.f, value.b[0], value.b[1], value.b[2], value.b[3]); первое был бы знак , но как распознать его? я имею в виду , введя -10 , я должен буду увидеть что? а порядок и целое с мантиссой будут в прямой последовательности?

Comment: @Elvin: Знак будет самым старшим битом самого старшего байта. Какой байт тут будет самым старшим зависит от платформы, но на x86 это будет `value.b[3]`. Вот старший бит `value.b[3]` - это и есть знак. Так что уместнее выводить в порядке `value.b[3]`, `value.b[2]`, `value.b[1]`, `value.b[0]`.

Comment: ,а если требуется вывести знак, мантиссу и порядок , то выводить так :  printf("%f = %x %x %x %x", value.f, value.b[3], value.b[2], value.b[1]); Где [3] - это знак.А [2]-порядок . [1] - мантисса ?

Answer (score -1):

1. Я тут структуры не вижу. Это `union` (объединение).

   В нем определены `float f` и `int i`. Если предположить, что на целевой платформе размер `float` и `int` - 4 байта, то само объединение тоже займёт 4 байта, а вот эти `f` и `i` будут вместе делить один и тот же кусок памяти.
2. Если ещё не отпал вопрос об инициализации:
   `= {10.f}` - инициализируем полей в порядке их объявления. В данном случае - только `f`.
3. `10.f`, `10.0f`, `.1f` - это все **валидные float-ы**. Просто каждый пишет как больше нравится.

А далее происходит магия:

```
// Выводим представление объединения как float
printf("%f\n", u.f); 
// Выводим как int в 16-ричном виде
printf("%x\n", u.i);
```

Что это значит? Это значит, что мы одни и те же 4 байта интерпретировали по-разному. В первом случае мы вообразили, что это `float`. Во втором, соответственно, `int`, и вывели в шестнадцатеричном виде.

Хотя данный пример не имеет практического смысла, ибо такое тоже сработает (хотя так, в общем-то, делать не стоит):

```
float u = 10.f; 
// Как float
printf("%f\n", u); 
// Как int в шестнадцатеричном
printf("%x\n", u);
```

Цель примера, видимо, заключается в демонстрации сути `union`-а.

Comment: Последний вариант - не "сработает". Это грубейшее неопределенное поведение, причем не какое-то теоретическое, а совершенно практическое: параметры в функции уже давно передаются в регистрах процессора, и целочисленные и плавающие значения передаются в разных регистрах. Более того, в языке С переинтерпретация памяти разрешается именно и только через `union`. Именно поэтому в примере использован `union`. Других вариантов переинтерпретации памяти просто нет.